# Does .Stat Suite support SDMX version 2.1

Tags: version, standards, sdmx

FAQ page says https://siscc.org/faq/

> The .Stat Suite is a native SDMX solution, supporting a complete end to end flow. It can consume, manage, and export SDMX 2.1 in SDMX-JSON, SDMX-ML, and SDMX-CSV formats.

While checking some of the latest implementations listed here: https://siscc.org/who-we-are/members/

For example lets look at http://andmebaas.stat.ee/

Choose one from many structures:  http://andmebaas.stat.ee/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/KK513

I can see 2.1 sdmx version incompatibilities

- URI Schema does not match the standard version 2.1, If its older version I could not find specification for such URI schema can you provide reference?
- xml message format uses `v2_0` schemas and different structure as well.

Is there a way to force 2.1 version for such endpoints?
I have tried to set Accept header `application/vnd.sdmx.structurespecificdata+xml;version=2.1`

And is this differences from standard because of .Stat suite implementation details or because of in this case stat.ee implemented it in this way.

P.S. If you know better place where I can ask this question please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The web site http://andmebaas.stat.ee/ does not use the .Stat Suite, but its predecessor and now legacy solution ".Stat". The underlying SDMX web service is also legacy and was made only for SDMX 2.0.

If you want to test the compatibility of the current SDMX web service, which is distributed as part of the .Stat Suite platform and based on a component built by Eurostat, please have a look at the "NSI ws with stable content" on this page: https://sis-cc.gitlab.io/dotstatsuite-documentation/getting-started/devops/#functional-staging-demo-environment.

If you have any question about the open-source .Stat Suite platform, please don't hesitate to check out the web site https://siscc.org/ or open a ticket in our repos: https://gitlab.com/sis-cc/.stat-suite